# Semisimple covers of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety.

The finite étale covers of $X$ are *measured* by the étale fundamental group $\pi_1^{\rm et}(X)$.

On the other hand, the Cox ring ${\rm Cox}(X)$ of $X$ (finitely generated or not) can help to *measure* the torus étale covers of $X$, i.e., the étale locally trivial $\mathbb{G}_m^k$-bundles over $X$.

Is there an algebraic object that *measures* the semisimple étale covers of $X$?  i.e., the étale locally trivial $G$-bundles over $X$ with $G$ semisimple?

Comment: What is the significance of italicising the word 'measure'?

Comment: That the corresponding covers are encripted in this algebraic group. In the fundamental group as normal subgroups, in the Cox ring as certain subalgebras.

Comment: Torsors for $\textbf{SL}_n$ are always locally trivial, even for the Zariski topology.  The moduli spaces of these torsors are essentially moduli of vector bundles with trivial determinant.

Comment: I think that [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07828v2) gives a partial answer to your question.